# Unique parent entries

Tags: playa, relationships

I'm making lookbooks:

Each look has (parent) contains one or more items (children). Each item has a brand. 
E.g. Picture 1 where a girls wears pants of Brand A, t-shirt of Brand B and a jacket of Brand A.
In my overview of Brand A, i want to show all pictures where the girls wears Brand A once. With this code Picture 1 appears 2x in the overview. How can I get this picture only show up once? 

I must be looking at code for too long. I'm sure there's a simple solution to this. Thank you for your help.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="items" search:item_brand="{last_segment}" dynamic="no"}
    {exp:playa:parents channel="looks" require_entry="yes"}
                    <img src="{look_image}" alt="{title}">
    {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/) for this, and split your data fetching from your markup assembly. Specifically, the `get_list` tag has a `unique="yes"` parameter that would allow you to only output each 'look' once:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="looks" parse_tags="yes"}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="items" search:item_brand="{last_segment}" dynamic="no"}
    {exp:playa:parents channel="looks" require_entry="yes"}
       {stash:the-title}{title}{/stash:the-title}
       {stash:the-image}{look_image}{/stash:the-image}
    {/exp:playa:parents}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

<ul>
   {exp:stash:get_list unique="yes" name="looks"}
      <li><img src="{the-image}" alt="{the-title}"></li>
   {/exp:stash:get_list} 
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I just had to add parse_depth="2" to set_list